# Is there a cordova plugin to read values from config.xml?

Tags: xml, cordova, config

I wish to read these values from my Cordova/PhoneGap application's `config.xml` at runtime:

- name
- copyright
- description

However, was surprised to see there is no '`Config`' feature in the API reference guide:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/index.html

I've resorted to writing my own function that reads and parses this file manually, however I feel like there must be an (existing) better way.

*Should developers be parsing config.xml manually to extract necessary info, or is there an existing plugin that can be used to do this?*

Comment: Stuck in the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939920/access-config-xml-preferences-from-javascript-plugins.

Comment: For future searchers: depending on your needs, you could put placeholders in a javascript file, and replace them with a build hook.  [This gist](https://gist.github.com/DavidFrahm/2ce16cb6aec90b2c428f) got me moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

You could use following code on iOS, WP7, WP8, Windows8, and probably Ubuntu

```
function readConfig() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, "application/xml");
        alert("Description : " + 
              doc.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).textContent);
    });
    xhr.open("get", "../config.xml", true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

for the Android you have to change path to file from `"../config.xml"` to `"../../android_res/xml/config.xml"`

Taken from Cordova mailing where discussed answer:
https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@cordova.apache.org/msg14313.html

Also there not-official plugin for reading configuration:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-labs/tree/cdvtest/cordova-plugin-appsettings

Comment: That code snippet won't work on Android or Blackberry. The discussion about that code on the mailing list indicate that writing a native plugin to return the location of `config.xml` is probably the most bulletproof approach. There's an [open ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6139) that hasn't been touched in nearly a year.

Answer (score 3):

For the ones who don't want to mess with the xhr queries, there are two plugins you can use:

[1 plugin-buildinfo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-buildinfo) (just for Android and IOS but sooo great)

[2 plugin-app-version](http://www.plugreg.com/plugin/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version) (lighter but supports more platforms)

To start quickly with the second one, all you need to do is adding the plugin into your project:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version.git
```

and calling where you want as follows:

```
cordova.getAppVersion(function (version) {
    alert(version);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use following Cordova plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customconfigparameters
```

Add your Custom Parameters in `Config.xml` as preference tags:

```
<preference name="name" value="Ibrahim"/>
<preference name="copyright" value="Direct Direction 2017"/>
<preference name="description" value="Information Technology"/>
```

Note: be sure the preference name should be a small letter (to work on IOS).

Then in your page Get a key's value from the `Config.xml` using the following script:

```
var paramkeyArray=["name","copyright","description"];
CustomConfigParameters.get(function(configData){
    console.log(configData.name);
    console.log(configData.copyright);
    console.log(configData.description);
},function(err){
  console.log(err);
},paramkeyArray);
```

For more detail see https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-customconfigparameters

Comment: Welcome! You may find it useful to review this guide https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code on formatting code blocks. Cheers!