# Access config.xml preferences from JavaScript plugins

Tags: cordova

In my project's `config.xml` I added a custom preference:

```
<preference name="FooBar" value="Baz" />
```

Then, in my custom plugin's JavaScript inside `<plugin>/www/plugin.js` I want to access the value of such feature.

Does Cordova exposes those values to the JavaScript side? I couldn't find any information in the documentation about it.

Tried:

```
var argscheck = require('cordova/argscheck');
argscheck.getValue('FooBar'); // Returns just FooBar
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a cordova plugin to read values from config.xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744269/is-there-a-cordova-plugin-to-read-values-from-config-xml)

Comment: For future searchers: depending on your needs, you could put placeholders in a javascript file, and replace them with a build hook.  [This gist](https://gist.github.com/DavidFrahm/2ce16cb6aec90b2c428f) got me moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use following code on iOS, WP7, WP8, Windows8, and probably Ubuntu

```
function readConfig() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, "application/xml");
        alert("Description : " + 
              doc.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).textContent);
    });
    xhr.open("get", "../config.xml", true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

for the Android you have to change path to file from `"../config.xml"` to `"../../android_res/xml/config.xml"`

Taken from Cordova mailing where discussed answer:
https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@cordova.apache.org/msg14313.html

Also there not-official plugin for reading configuration:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-labs/tree/cdvtest/cordova-plugin-appsettings

Comment: regarding that "not-official plugin", do you happen to know how to use it?  It has no documentation.  I have it installed but I have no idea how to run it.  I see no function or object attached to window or navigator that allows me to run it.

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out.  I had to update js-module section of the plugin.xml in order for the appsettings method to be accessible. 

`<js-module src="www/appsettings.js" name="appsettings">
        <clobbers target="navigator.appsettings" />
    </js-module>`