# Differentiate between Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.0 programatically

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I want to differentitate between windows 8.1 and windows 10.0 target version programatically.

I'am using cordova, javascript. How do i find the difference, so that i can write functions for 8.1 as well as 10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two methods:**

- Use cordova [device.platform](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/#deviceplatform) API which gives [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/#windows-phone-8-quirks)
- Use the library [UA-parser](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js) which has list of popular device detection with OS versions.

Comment: @Matarishvan You asked for programatic way right? can you explain a bit more.. detail

Comment: is there any way to read the windows-target-version through javascript

Comment: @Matarishvan from which xml? you want to read `config.xml`or `manifest` inside Windows project?

Comment: config.xml .. we have preference - windows-target-version which is set to 10.0 or 8.1.. i want to get this specific information

Comment: currently developing cordova windows app for 8.1 and 10.0. need to know which `windows-target-version` programatically through javascript, or anyother way to find the target version

Comment: @Matarishvan Nope you can't read the config.xml after building the Windows app. Anyother is the one i have pointed you in the above answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144376/discussion-between-matarishvan-and-nirus).

Answer (score 0):

You can make an HTTP request to read version from xml.
Replace the URL with the xml file you want to read. I hope it works.

```
function readConfig() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, "application/xml");
        alert("Description : " + 
              doc.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).textContent);
    });
    xhr.open("get", "../../android_res/xml/config.xml", true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Refer : 
 [Is there a cordova plugin to read values from config.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744269/is-there-a-cordova-plugin-to-read-values-from-config-xml/25152966#25152966)

Comment: A mighty specific slice there - I would be surprised if this worked across different browsers, let alone operating systems...

Comment: yes it does work in chrome/mozilla/ edge, and slice to get only version information the output would look like this "Windows NT 10.0"

Comment: I need 'windows-target-version' which is defined in cordova XML... i think this is not the one i want

Comment: you exactly copied other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25152966/1848109. Instead you could have put the source link. Please dont steal the credits. Atleast metion the original answer.